# Using WordPress meta_query to find the post title

Tags: wordpress, search, metadata

I have the following and it works with the meta_query as this passes custom meta properties but I'm struggling to get it to just search through the title of the custom post type.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'title',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => $teamName
        )
    )
);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine, using Search Parameter of WP Query, which search Titles also:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
                  'post_type' => 'team',
                  's' => $teamName,
               );
?>
```